# Sitecore MVC ViewRendereing and GlassMapper

Tags: razor, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I would like to create a breadcrumb based on Razor on Sitecore 8 MVC.
I created a page template with some property that would be use for it.
View rendering was created and added to layout item (page).
I have created a cshtml file for this rendering with while loop

```
 <ul>
    @{
        var parentItem = Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem;
        while (parentItem != null)
        {
            if (parentItem["Include in breadcrumb"] != "0")
            {
                <li>@parentItem["Short Title"]</li>
            }
            parentItem = parentItem.Parent;
        }
    }        
</ul>
```

But it is looks not very optimal for me, I would like to use Glass Mapper for it

I created a class with ancestor access

```cs
public class Breadcrumb
{
    [SitecoreQuery("ancestor-or-self::*[@#Include in breadcrumb#='1']", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Breadcrumb> Ancestors { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Include in breadcrumb")]
    public virtual bool IncludeIn { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Short Title")]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't know how to 'say' to sitecore use it for my View rendering.
I don't have any specific controller for page.

Is it possible to use some how glass mapper with View rendering ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually is done via inherits directive at the top of your view:

```
@using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc
@inherits GlassView<Breadcrumb>
```

Then on page you may use your model as normal; if, for a case, you want to have your title Page Editor friendly - then you may use the following construction to access your model properties:

```
@Editable(x=>x.Title)
```

Comment: Small question how to use @Editable(x=>x.Title) for item in foreach loop ?

Comment: Use that only if you need your breadcrump to be page editable.Common sense tells me that it is not your case. But if yes - just replace @parentItem["Short Title"] with @Editable(x=>x.ShortTitle) or whatever property name your model has. More documentation with examples here: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation

Answer (score 4):

Martin is correct. However, if you're using Glass v4, do note you are not required to inherit from `GlassView` and instead can use the more natural `@model` + `@Html` HtmlHelper syntax if you want.

```
@Html.Glass().Editable(x => x.Title);
```